# Instrument cluster swap between a 96 BMW Z3 and a 96 BMW E36 318i?

Tags: electrical, bmw, instrument-cluster

I recently got an instrument cluster replacement off eBay for a 1996 318i for a friend. The link has been provided below. But something I noticed is that the E36 318i has a MPG gauge while the cluster I purchased doesn't have one. I did some googling and found that the 1996 Z3 cluster doesn't have the MPG gauge and looks exactly like the one I got. The harness connectors all seem to be alike. Anyone here has any experience with swapping the two?

https://www.ebay.com/itm/1996-BMW-318i-Instrument-Cluster-Speedometer-8360490/192702969506?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to check the wires in all the connectors to make sure the functions match, both on the vehicle side and the new dash side.

Even if all the positions match, things that are in the new dash that were not in the original may not work as sensors or ecu routines may not be present.

Be **very** careful, one wire wrong can cause a fire...

I did a similar swap on an Audi I had, putting a petrol dash into a diesel car so I could have a rev counter. This meant making a pulse generator (well conditioner) with sensor to drive the rev counter as a diesel does not have a coil...

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you please guide me to a link pr provide a picture of the pin assignment of the cluster for the Z3. I found the pin assignment table for the E36.