# Feasibility of Cluster Swap (Civic 01 EX to Civic 04 LX - Both Auto Trans, both Sedans)

Tags: civic, instrument-cluster

I have taken on a project for feasibility and want to see if I can achieve a swap as the title suggests and I see multiple references to successful swaps for a Auto Cluster into a Manual Civic.   Is an Auto Trans-to-Auto Trans in this case doable?

Comment: Cluster, then see my advice here : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/68546/10976